# Using OpenCL and GPU is not increasing fps performance of my Camera

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencl, gpu

I compiled this simple color tracking  Image Processing program using OpenCV and Visual Studio 2012.
First I compiled it using CPU.
Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

 int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {
    time_t t= time(0);
    VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from web cam

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
         return -1;
    }
     double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
   double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("Control", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "Control"

  int iLowH = 0;
 int iHighH = 179;

  int iLowS = 0; 
 int iHighS = 255;

  int iLowV = 0;
 int iHighV = 255;

  //Create track bars in "Control" window
 cvCreateTrackbar("LowH", "Control", &iLowH, 179); //Hue (0 - 179)
 cvCreateTrackbar("HighH", "Control", &iHighH, 179);

  cvCreateTrackbar("LowS", "Control", &iLowS, 255); //Saturation (0 - 255)
 cvCreateTrackbar("HighS", "Control", &iHighS, 255);

  cvCreateTrackbar("LowV", "Control", &iLowV, 255); //Value (0 - 255)
 cvCreateTrackbar("HighV", "Control", &iHighV, 255);

    int fps=0;
    int cur=0;
    while (true)
    {
    fps++;
        t=time(0);
        struct tm *tmp = gmtime(&t);

        int h= (t/360) %24;
        int m= (t/60) %60;
        int s = t%60;
        if(cur !=s)
        {
            cout<<fps<<endl;
            fps=0;
            cur=s;
        }
        Mat imgOriginal;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
             break;
        }

    Mat imgHSV;

   cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV

  Mat imgThresholded;

   inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded); //Threshold the image

  //morphological opening (remove small objects from the foreground)
  erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
  dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 

   //morphological closing (fill small holes in the foreground)
  dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 
  erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );

   imshow("Thresholded Image", imgThresholded); //show the thresholded image
  imshow("Original", imgOriginal); //show the original image

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
       }
    }

   return 0;

}
```

My Camera was giving an fps of 16.
Then I compiled this program using OpenCL (GPU  Support).
 Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp>
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

 int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {
    time_t t= time(0);
    VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from web cam

    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
         return -1;
    }
     double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
   double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("Control", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "Control"

  int iLowH = 0;
 int iHighH = 179;

  int iLowS = 0; 
 int iHighS = 255;

  int iLowV = 0;
 int iHighV = 255;

  //Create track bars in "Control" window
 cvCreateTrackbar("LowH", "Control", &iLowH, 179); //Hue (0 - 179)
 cvCreateTrackbar("HighH", "Control", &iHighH, 179);

  cvCreateTrackbar("LowS", "Control", &iLowS, 255); //Saturation (0 - 255)
 cvCreateTrackbar("HighS", "Control", &iHighS, 255);

  cvCreateTrackbar("LowV", "Control", &iLowV, 255); //Value (0 - 255)
 cvCreateTrackbar("HighV", "Control", &iHighV, 255);

    int fps=0;
    int cur=0;
    while (true)
    {
    fps++;
        t=time(0);
        struct tm *tmp = gmtime(&t);

        int h= (t/360) %24;
        int m= (t/60) %60;
        int s = t%60;
        if(cur !=s)
        {
            cout<<fps<<endl;
            fps=0;
            cur=s;
        }
        Mat imgOriginal;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
             break;
        }

    Mat imgHSV;

   cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV

  Mat imgThresholded;

   inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded); //Threshold the image

  //morphological opening (remove small objects from the foreground)
    ocl::oclMat alpha(imgThresholded);
    ocl::erode(alpha,alpha, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
    ocl::dilate( alpha, alpha, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 

   //morphological closing (fill small holes in the foreground)
    ocl::dilate( alpha, alpha, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 
    ocl::erode(alpha, alpha, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
    imgThresholded = Mat(alpha);
   imshow("Thresholded Image", imgThresholded); //show the thresholded image
  imshow("Original", imgOriginal); //show the original image

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
       }
    }

   return 0;

}
```

But now i am getting a fps = 10 . Please can someone tell Why is this Happening.
I read somewhere that GPU Support improves the fps performance. Graphic Card I am Using Is AMD RAEDON .

Comment: if (waitKey(30) == 27), 30ms means 33 FPS max already .  5ms should work too and give you more fps

Comment: which gpu? HD7730 GDDR3  or R9-295x2 ?

Comment: HD 8730M @huseyintugrulbuyukisik

Answer (score 2):

GPU is designed for massive throughput, but it takes lot of time to move the data from CPU memory to GPU memory. You should not think that GPU is always increasing the fps. It all depends on how well the power of GPU is harvested.

In your case it seems like you are doing quite little work for each frame. So my guess is that your system is using most of the time moving frames to the GPU and moving results back.

Comment: Transfer multiple frames at a time

Comment: You could also try reading a new frame from video with CPU while your GPU is working on the previous frame. You can try this by moving your frame reading code to be after last `ocl::erode` and before blocking read `Mat(alpha)`. This is not absolute way to do it because compiler might move code around, but definitely thing I would try in your case.

Answer (score 1):

(as  maZZZu commented)

You are doing serial computations. Add pipelining. Then when a frame is being captured, one last frame is being computed by opencl at the same time. You could overlap even more steps like:

- get video data
- copy to gpu
- compute
- get to cpu
- visualise?

then only the biggest time consuming step will be visible on FPS. If copy to gpu is taking 20ms, then others will be hidden and program will show 50FPS.

```
- Time 1: get video data 1
- (Time 2: get video data 2) and (copy data 1 to gpu)
- (Time 3: get video data 3) and (copy data 2 to gpu) and (compute data 1)
- (Time 4: get video data 4) and (copy data 3 to gpu) and (compute data 2) and ..
- (Time 5: get video data 5) and (copy data 4 to gpu) and (compute data 3) and ..
- (Time 6: get video data 6) and (copy data 5 to gpu) and (compute data 4) and ..
- (Time 7: get video data 8) and (copy data 6 to gpu) and (compute data 5) and ..
```

so if copying to gpu takes %45 and getting result back takes %45 of time, FPS should increase by %90 with just hiding one of them behind other.